# Displaying HTML body content in Windows phone without URI

Tags: html, xaml

How can I display an HTML body's content in Windows Phone without having the URI? I have the text, but I cannot display it in a normal textbox since it has HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing every instance of `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;` before printing the content.

Comment: isn't there maybe some type of conversion utility, I am not sure how it works, but I cant do that since I am trying to bind to the html content

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but isn't there a more "correct" way of doing things, instead of looping over everything and removing the html tags, visual studio should have a control or something which caters for this

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved it myself,

I simply added a class which does the conversion, and then in the Model, I returned the value after converting it;

```
private string _body;
public string Body
{
    get { return _body; }
    set { _body = HTMLHelper.ConvertHtmlToText(value); }
}
```

Comment: In order to bind to that property, you may also need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to have the view get notified about property value changes.